# Use MOSFET to Change Voltage With PWM

Tags: sensors, transistor, mosfet

Ok so forgive me for being an amateur but I'm having a situation that's driving me nuts.

I have a sensor that I have to cycle between +5VDC and +1.4VDC every 60 seconds. I'm using an ATTiny85 with the 8Mhz internal clock fuse set.

What I was hoping was to use a 2N7000 N-Channel MOSFET to control the cycling of the voltage. So my thought is to have +5VDC on the Drain and a PWM signal on the Gate with the + side of the sensor connected to the Source. I am thinking that using PWM and adjusting the duty cycle on the Gate will allow me to adjust the voltage that is seen at the Source but what I'm seeing is a variation of +1.4VDC @28% duty cycle and +3.6VDC at 100% duty cycle.

I can't figure out why +3.6VDC is the best I can do. The PWM is coming from PB1 on the ATTiny85 and the +5VDC is coming from the main voltage source that also feeds the ATTiny85. The current draw of the sensor is 140mA max.

[image: Schematic]

Ok so I haven't had any luck using a BJT or a single component to perform this voltage change so I started on a different approach using two 1N7000, with one being in an inverter configuration.  My though is the pin from the MCU will go high, which will turn on both FET's, with one supplying 5V and the other sinking to ground.  When the MCU pin goes low, both FET's turn off, which stops the 5V flow and the sink to ground, which then will allow the path through a voltage divider into my sensor at 1.4V.  The issue I am having is the second FET is smoking, and by that I mean the sucker heats up like crazy and one even let the smoke out!  I cannot for the life of me figure out WTF I am missing in this configuration.  Here is the new schematic and Q1 is the FET that is smokin.

[image: Version 2]

Comment: Please post a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Using a N-type transistor as a high-side switch is inefficient unless you have some way of driving the gate above the positive rail. The most you can reasonably expect at the source is the gate voltage minus the gate threshold voltage, V<sub>GS(th)</sub>. The typical threshold voltage of the 2N7000 as given in the datasheet is 2.1V, which means that it is a bit remarkable that you are able to get a voltage as high as you have (5V - 2.1V = 2.9V).

The way to fix this is to switch to a P-type transistor (and flip it around) since its threshold voltage is negative.

Comment: Not sure about how the P-Type BJT would fit in there but definitely open to it.  I'm mobile at the moment so don't have access to the schematic but as soon as I can I will upload it.

Comment: I added a rough schematic. The heating element is a 33 ohm resistive element in the sensor that needs to cycle between 5V and 1.4V.

Comment: @JW52761: Add it to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, the mobile client is not very intuitive.  Anyway, it's attached and I'm wondering if I should use an opamp in non-inverting mode with a gain of x3 to enable driving the gate above the +5VDC rail voltage to allow the source to have a full +5VDC on it.
Forgive me if that sounds silly, I am still learning as I go.

Comment: @JW52761: You can't drive an op amp above its positive supply. Change the resistor.

Comment: The resistor is representative of the sensor's heater and is out of my control.  It's data sheet states the heater's resistance is 31 ohm +/- 3 ohm, so I used R1 in the schematic just for representation.

What needs to happen is the heater needs to run at 5V for 60 seconds, then at 1.4V for 90 seconds, then repeat.  So, I guess the solution would be to increase the supply voltage to +9VDC, which means I have to mess with voltage regulation and such which I haven't messed with yet.

Comment: Did I say resistor? I meant transistor, sorry.

Comment: I did try a 2N3904 but couldn't get it to change the voltage based on PWM duty cycle.  I looked at a 2N3906 but couldn't figure out how to get it into the circuit.

Comment: Ok, so did a slight change on paper that uses a LM7805 for the ATTiny85 and the sensor's +5VDC input.  The input voltage I've moved to +9VDC which will input into the LM7805 and into the positive rail of a LM358 op-amp.  I'm thinking 2.2 ohms for both the Rf and Rg resistors, which should give me a gain of 2x if I'm thinking right.  

So by fiddling with the PWM of the ATTiny85 through the non-inverting input of the LM358 I should be able to get the 2N7000 to swing between 1.4VDC and 5VDC, and since the Vgs(th) is between .8 and 2.1 VDC I should have no problem with 1.4VDC.